# Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine can't set parallel execution

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-jvm

P. Korstanje, please help me,

Was created file junit-platform.properties with following config

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=16
```

Used gradle

cucumber = '5.6.0'

cucumber runner

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

hookClass

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootCucumberApplication.class)
public class UIHooks {}
```

SpringApp

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"io.tpd.springbootcucumber"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"io.tpd.springbootcucumber"})
public class SpringBootCucumberApplication {}
```

As an example, I tried to use https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/junit-platform-engine/README.md#surefire-and-gradle-workarounds for Gradle

but val consoleLauncherTest by registering(JavaExec::class) solution and @Cucumber didn't help me

Comment: Looks like you're still using JUnit 4 and `cucumber-junit`. Also `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` won't do you any good for Cucumber. Might be worth focusing on the minimal aspect of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Might even be worth leaving spring boot out of it entirely. See if you can get a hello word kinda thing to work.